# How to trigger an increase of 1D array?

Tags: labview

I'm new on LabVIEW and I need some help to trigger the increment of all items of 1D array. Basically what I need to do is: when element of "#found" increase by one a led should light.
Anyone could help me?
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but do you want to detect (light a LED) change of ALL or ANY elements? Does the change need to be exactly +1 or any positive change? Negative count too?

Comment: Increases by one compared to what? The value it had in the previous iteration of your For loop, or something else?